# Where is bpy.context.material?

Tags: python

In the api documentation there is a [`bpy.context.material`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.material).
However, when I type `bpy.context.m` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> in the *Python console* it completes to `bpy.context.mode`, suggesting that there are no attributes of `bpy.context` that begin with `m` besides `mode`.

Where is `bpy.context.material` and how can I access it?

Comment: It's under the **Buttons Context** heading; don't know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is listed in the "Buttons Context" section it is only available on such a context. The context in the *Python Console* inside Blender is a [Screen Context](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.context.html#screen-context).

This is an example where a Buttons Context is used:

```
class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = 'material'

    def draw(self, context):
        # context is a Buttons Context

        # Result: "<bpy_struct, Material("Material")>"
        print(context.material)
```

Please note that `context.material` wouldn't be accessible if the field `bl_context` was something else than `'material'`.

Answer (score 2):

Best guess:

You can see that bpy.context.material is listed under the "Buttons Context" section in the API doc link you posted (other sections are "View3D Context", "Screen Context" etc.). Based on what I found during my search, it looks like this is a context from 2.4x that is no longer available in 2.5x+. "Buttons Context" seems to be an old name for what we now know as the properties editor.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Reference/Buttons/Window

It seems that this is old code (or old documentation) that just wasn't removed, but take it with a grain of salt, I could easily be wrong.

**Edit** (from comment below, which author identified as the sought-after code):
If I get what you're looking for with this attribute, you might want to try bpy.context.object.active_material.

Comment: If I get what you're looking for with this attribute, you might want to try bpy.context.object.active_material. I would guess that you already know this though.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for: **bpy.data.materials**

I believe that contains all the materials available in the Blender session.

If you would rather get a specific material or a list of materials assigned to an object you can access those here:
**bpy.data.objects['objname'].data.materials**

For example:

```
>>> bpy.data.objects[0].data.materials.items()
[('walls.017', bpy.data.materials['walls.017'])]
```

Comment: I wanted `context.material` because I want to get the active material. (AFAIK, `bpy.data.materials` just gives a collection of all materials in the file with no way to tell what the active one is)

Comment: Maybe this then? bpy.context.active_object.data.materials

I guess it would be helpful to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. It's still a collection though, I just want the active material (`bpy.context.active_object.active_material` as [mentioned by Qutorial](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3437/where-is-bpy-context-material/3485?noredirect=1#comment5934_3479) does what I want)